# Why is the AutoConfiguration not executing when using the applicationcontextrunner?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I am trying to test my auto configuration class, and I'm expecting that the beans from the auto configuration class will get loaded into the spring context.

Here is my test

```java
public class CompanyHttpClientAutoConfigurationTest {

    private final ApplicationContextRunner contextRunner = new ApplicationContextRunner()
            .withConfiguration(AutoConfigurations.of(CodecsAutoConfiguration.class, ClientHttpConnectorAutoConfiguration.class, WebClientAutoConfiguration.class, CompanyHttpClientAutoConfiguration.class));

    @Test
    public void httpClientInjected(){
        //ARRANGE
        //ACT
        //ASSERT
        this.contextRunner.withPropertyValues("org.company.http.clients.someHttpClient.baseUrl=http://localhost:8080").run(context -> assertNotNull(context.getBean(SomeHttpClient.class)));
    }

    @CompanyHttpClient(name = "someHttpClient")
    interface SomeHttpClient{
        @GetExchange
        String get();
    }
}
```

Here is the autoconfiguration class.

```java
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(WebClientAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan("org.company.http")
@ConditionalOnBean(WebClient.Builder.class)
public class CompanyHttpClientAutoConfiguration {
}
```

The autoconfiguration does a component scan of the package where it would load up our Registrar class which registers the beans. The problem that I'm seeing is that the `ApplicationContextRunner` loads the autoconfiguration bean, but it doesn't execute/run it when invoking the `run` method.

I've added the dependent auto configurations to the application context, and I've added the necessary spring properties into the environment, but it still seems like the auto configuration does not get triggered.

Here is the error that I'm seeing along with `DEBUG` logs of the test. Any suggestions?

```
19:10:05.452 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6bb75258
19:10:05.459 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
19:10:05.540 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor'
19:10:05.541 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory'
19:10:05.542 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor'
19:10:05.543 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor'
19:10:05.545 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
19:10:05.545 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.internalConfigurationPropertiesBinder'
19:10:05.549 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'codecsAutoConfiguration'
19:10:05.551 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'clientHttpConnectorAutoConfiguration'
19:10:05.551 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'webClientAutoConfiguration'
19:10:05.552 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'companyHttpClientAutoConfiguration'
19:10:05.552 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$DefaultCodecsConfiguration'
19:10:05.552 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'defaultCodecCustomizer'
19:10:05.555 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.codec-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.codec.CodecProperties'
19:10:05.557 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.BoundConfigurationProperties'
19:10:05.591 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Autowiring by type from bean name 'defaultCodecCustomizer' via factory method to bean named 'spring.codec-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.codec.CodecProperties'
19:10:05.592 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.codec.CodecsAutoConfiguration$JacksonCodecConfiguration'
19:10:05.593 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesRegistrar.methodValidationExcludeFilter'
19:10:05.597 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.netty.ReactorNettyConfigurations$ReactorResourceFactoryConfiguration'
19:10:05.597 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'reactorResourceFactory'
19:10:05.598 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.reactor.netty-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.netty.ReactorNettyProperties'
19:10:05.599 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Autowiring by type from bean name 'reactorResourceFactory' via factory method to bean named 'spring.reactor.netty-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.netty.ReactorNettyProperties'
19:10:05.604 [Test worker] DEBUG reactor.util.Loggers -- Using Slf4j logging framework
19:10:05.615 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.logging.InternalLoggerFactory -- Using SLF4J as the default logging framework
19:10:05.616 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- -Dio.netty.noUnsafe: false
19:10:05.616 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- Java version: 17
19:10:05.617 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- sun.misc.Unsafe.theUnsafe: available
19:10:05.617 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- sun.misc.Unsafe.copyMemory: available
19:10:05.617 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- sun.misc.Unsafe.storeFence: available
19:10:05.617 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- java.nio.Buffer.address: available
19:10:05.617 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- direct buffer constructor: unavailable: Reflective setAccessible(true) disabled
19:10:05.618 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- java.nio.Bits.unaligned: available, true
19:10:05.618 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.allocateUninitializedArray(int): unavailable: class io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0$7 cannot access class jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.misc to unnamed module @376a0d86
19:10:05.619 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent0 -- java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long, int): unavailable
19:10:05.619 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- sun.misc.Unsafe: available
19:10:05.624 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- maxDirectMemory: 536870912 bytes (maybe)
19:10:05.624 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.tmpdir: /var/folders/j7/j1xm2wyd74g8p5hddl8wsd4h0000gp/T (java.io.tmpdir)
19:10:05.625 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.bitMode: 64 (sun.arch.data.model)
19:10:05.625 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- Platform: MacOS
19:10:05.625 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.maxDirectMemory: -1 bytes
19:10:05.625 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.uninitializedArrayAllocationThreshold: -1
19:10:05.626 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.CleanerJava9 -- java.nio.ByteBuffer.cleaner(): available
19:10:05.626 [Test worker] DEBUG io.netty.util.internal.PlatformDependent -- -Dio.netty.noPreferDirect: false
19:10:05.647 [Test worker] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources -- [http] resources will use the default LoopResources: DefaultLoopResources {prefix=reactor-http, daemon=true, selectCount=10, workerCount=10}
19:10:05.648 [Test worker] DEBUG reactor.netty.tcp.TcpResources -- [http] resources will use the default ConnectionProvider: reactor.netty.resources.DefaultPooledConnectionProvider@25b5c5e3
19:10:05.648 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.ClientHttpConnectorConfiguration$ReactorNetty'
19:10:05.648 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientAutoConfiguration$WebClientCodecsConfiguration'
19:10:05.648 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory -- Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'exchangeStrategiesCustomizer'
19:10:05.669 [Test worker] DEBUG org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext -- Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6bb75258, started on Sun May 28 19:10:05 EDT 2023

No qualifying bean of type 'org.company.http.autoconfig.companyHttpClientAutoConfigurationTest$SomeHttpClient' available
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.company.http.autoconfig.companyHttpClientAutoConfigurationTest$SomeHttpClient' available
```